# i cant set the size and position of a webview embedded in an app

Tags: android, webview

Using the code below in Java I can 'embed' a webview into the app screen i GameMaker App.

```
package ${YYAndroidPackageName};


import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.Window;

public class WebView2 extends RunnerActivity {
    public static String theurl;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity);
        mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);


        mWebView.loadUrl(theurl);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);
}
}
```

But I dont want the webview to take up the entire apps screen, i want to create a webview that is 320px X 50px and positioned at the bottom of the screen.

Is there any way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desire result by creating it in xml then loading it in java.

**Result**

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String theurl = "https://www.google.com.pk";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl(theurl);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <!--<WebView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/webView"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="320px"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="50px"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />-->
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can i inject that into the android manifest i dont think game make lets us add code to that xml file.  Only to android manifest and Gradle

Comment: mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  doesnt that assume there is a 'object' defined in the layout called webview?  i dont really want to reference any object, i want to tell it what screen/activity to embed the webview onto then resize it to say 300,100px and the position near the bottom of the app screen, while still being able to see the game and use the app.  Then i want to be able to close the webview